# ROC curve from y_true and y_pred

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I have not worked much with ROC. Is it possible to plot the ROC curve with just `y_true = ['A','B','A','B']` and `y_pred=['A','B','A','A']`?

Or is it necessary to have the model to be able to get the scores?

I want to use [sklearns implementations](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you will need the non-thresholded data. The fact that you have already predictions A and B means that you already applied some kind of threshold, deciding which output belongs to which class.

A ROC curve is supposed to help you find exactly that threshold at which you model works best for you.

Depending on with which model/implementation/code you work there is surely some way to get the probabilities.